# Connecting site to phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, html, mysql, hosting

I have a website that has forms, images, text, etc. I want extract data from the forms and keep a record of them in mySQL. In order to do this do I need to change the file extension from '.html' to '.php'? And if so then will this effect any inline css?

Also, when I need to connect to the server via the php, how to I know the database username, database password, and the database host?

I have go daddy as the web host, and use the CPanel they provide to access the phpmyadmin

Thanks - any help is highly appreciated!

This is the PHP code I have so far, and I keep getting error alerts when I run the test through XAMPP:

[image]

[image]

Comment: phpMyAdmin is **not a database** its a database query tool. However **MySQL is a database**!

Comment: sorry about that - my bad - as you can tell I am pretty new to server-side-scripting haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer stated, use `pdo` or `mysqli` instead of 'mysql`.
A good way to use PDO is to put the connection code within a file, and include this file anywhere you need to make use of the database.

Let's call this file `dbconnector.php`.

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO($connectionString, 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now, wherever you want to use database, just use :-

```
include 'dbconnector.php'
```

Now, you can access the connection variable via `$conn`.

Read more on PDO.
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_connect()` is already deprecated please consider using `mysqli` or `PDO`.
PDO . database connection example :-
   You should create a separate class containing the functions for basic operation in database and keep that file separate from your other code , just inherit the class and use the connection and function .

```
 <?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Prafulla Kumar Sahu - How do I implement this in the code?

Comment: just updated my answer there code for database connection using  PDO.